What does "hanging on to their virility" mean?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

He knew that sometimes old spies, even the best of them, were a little like old lovers; as age crept up on them, they began to cheat, out of fear that their powers were deserting them. They pretended they had it all in the memory, but in secret they were hanging on to their virility, in secret they wrote things down, often in some home-made code

Wouldn't it be more logical to simply say "They pretended they had it all in the memory, but in secret they wrote things down"? Doesn't "hanging on to their virility" suggest memorizing everything?

"Hanging on to their virility" seems to mean "hanging on to their reputation for virility". They pretend to their fellow-spies that they have everything in their memory. This is what is expected of a good spy, so that an enemy can never find any information written down.  But in reality the strength (virility) of their mind is no longer up to it, so they actually write things down. A home-made code would be easily broken by an enemy who discovered it.

This was my initial assumption, but on second reading I think the OP is right to question it: if "virility" here is a simile for "memory" then hanging on to it should be strenuously trying to memorise things and not writing them down.
